# Terminology for lecturing modes (for CV)

Tags: cv, lecturer

In the country I did my PhD in, at a lot of courses there are lectures by a professor covering theory, and then lectures by a PhD student which cover exercises, examples, clarifications, etc. Those are lectures which require preparation, standing in front of a full class, just like the "main" lectures. My question is, how should I refer to it in my CV. Maybe if I write "Teaching Assistant", in the US it might be understood as something with less weight than what I described?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am a teaching assistant in the US and I do this type of classes. They are called "review sessions", "recitations" or "discussions", depending on the department and the institution. Following professors'  advice, in my academic CV, in my "teaching experience" section, I list each class I have TAed for and I write a short sentence specifying if I only graded assignments or I also held review sessions or designed materials or something else.

Comment: Thank you! So, I guess if I write "TA (recitation)" next to the item, it will be clear?

Comment: I guess but, again, I was strongly recommended to add a line with a description of all the tasks (if you are searching for an academic job).